# Pointing a delegate to a method in a class

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to assign a delegate to a method that belongs to another class object.

```
TestingClass testObj = new TestingClass();
Delegate myDelegate = testObj.testMethod;   //syntax error
```

My intention is to point `myDelegate` to the method `testMethod` in `testObj`. The above code has syntax error.

What is the right syntax to do this in C#?

Comment: What is the syntax error? And what is the signature of testMethod?

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: @jpmc26 The IDE just highlights the second line as having syntax error and doesn't allow for compilation.

Comment: If you try to compile, the IDE will give you the full error.

Comment: Please show the definition of `testMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really intent on using delegates--which can be handy for creating a well-named type--define one of your own:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void D1();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testObj = new Program();
        D1 myDelegate = testObj.TestMethod;
        myDelegate.Invoke();
    }

    void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's virtually never a need to define your own delegate.  You can, and should, use `Action` or `Func` whenever possible (which is almost all of the time).  It's quicker, easier, and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You should assign it to a variable with a compatible delegate type e.g.

```
Action myDelegate = testObj.testMethod;
```

The delegate type depends on the definition of `testMethod`.

Comment: There are [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.action.aspx) definitions for up to 16 arguments as of .NET 4.5. You would use them like so: Action<String, String> if testMethod takes 2 string arguments. Furthermore, there's the [Func  delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) with it's many variations for methods with a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jon Skeets tutorial on how to use as well as create Delegates it's straight and simple to understand [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

Here is a simple example and explanation on how you can use it based on an example I wrote for you

```
//Define a delegate here in your Class
public delegate void MyMessageHandler(string message);
```

You can then use it like this:

```
public void DoWork(MyMessageHandler callback)
{
    string message = "";
    ....
    callback(message);
}
```

You then call it like this:

```
public Main()
{
    DoWork(ProcessMessages);
}
public void ProcessMessages(string message)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: There's virtually never a need to define your own delegate.  You can, and should, use `Action` or `Func` whenever possible (which is almost all of the time).  It's quicker, easier, and more readable.

Comment: I understand Servy but I was providing an example based on the OP's existing code

Comment: And based on the OP's existing code why does he need to define his own delegate instead of using `Action<string>`?

Comment: Yes he could have done it that way.. I Understand the Action<sting> being a Collection at that point so what's your point in the constant questioning..?? have a good night It's MILLER TIME